Nvidia GPU does not release memery after running python/pytroch
After running the GPU, the GPU memory is not getting released as shown in the smi. May I know how to fix this issue by releasing memory after running the code (mainly Pytorch/Python)?
  Using Ubuntu 24.04
  Drivers: 550.120
  GPU: RTX 4070 Ti Super


For some reason python is still running. Kill it. Check the nvidia-smi output and find the line that corresponds to your python execution.
Look at the process identifier (PID). In your image is 11603. Kill it kill -9 11603.
Or if you want the process to keep running you can empty the cache:
import torch
torch.cuda.empty_cache()

